# I want to get null count of dyanmic column name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE   ts(IN col1 varchar(100),IN val int, OUT res int)
BEGIN

SET @s=CONCAT("SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(",col1,",'')) INTO  @res FROM demo WHERE d=",val);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SELECT @res INTO res;

END
```

i get following error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

i want to used this stored procedure in PHP??? please help!!

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL is not SQL92, try:

```
sum(case when field is null then 1 else 0 end)
```

for better portability

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to execute this stored procedure in PHP using mysqli but , it does not work!

Comment: your query is not dynamic enough to warrant a stored procedure or the dynamic query generation. consider generating the query in PHP and dropping the procedure all together.